# Posting the data using the for loop for each array in the inside array with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

My data include one Sensor and too many Alarm related this Sensor. I am trying create many Alarm using for loop. Then I want to use this Alarm variable in Sensor json object.
However I couldn't this. Please help me. How can I create Alarm array and then send as a parameter this array to Sensor object.

The data package I want to send is as follows:

```
  "Alarm": [
    {
      "AlarmCommunication": [
        {
          "AlarmCommunicationID": 0,
          "AlarmId": 0,
          "CommunicationTypeId": 1
        }
      ],
      "AlarmWorkingTime": [
        {
          "AlarmWorkingTimeID": 0,
          "AlarmId": 0,
          "WorkingTimeTypeId": 1
        }
      ],
      "AlarmID": 0,
      "SensorId": 0,
      "DensityTypeId": 5,
      "DurationTime": 30,
      "isActive": true
    }
  ],
    "Alarm": [
    {
      "AlarmCommunication": [
        {
          "AlarmCommunicationID": 0,
          "AlarmId": 0,
          "CommunicationTypeId": 1
        }
      ],
      "AlarmWorkingTime": [
        {
          "AlarmWorkingTimeID": 0,
          "AlarmId": 0,
          "WorkingTimeTypeId": 1
        }
      ],
      "AlarmID": 0,
      "SensorId": 0,
      "DensityTypeId": 3,
      "DurationTime": 40,
      "isActive": true
    }
  ],
  "SensorID": 0,
  "RoadId": 11,
  "GivenSensorID": "TEST",
  "LocationX": "32.55",
  "LocationY": "42.56",
  "SegmentId": 91,
  "isActive": true
}
```

I tried posting it with the following code blog, but it didn't work.
Where am i making a mistake

```
for (var i = 1; i <= alarms.length; i++) {
        data.Alarm.AlarmCommunication.push({
            "AlarmCommunicationID": 0,
            "AlarmId": 0,
            "CommunicationTypeId": 1
        });
        data.Alarm.AlarmWorkingTime.push({
            "AlarmWorkingTimeID": 0,
            "AlarmId": 0,
            "WorkingTimeTypeId": 1
        });
        data.Alarm.push({
            "AlarmID": 0,
            "SensorId": 0,
            "DensityTypeId": 1,
            "DurationTime": 1,
            "isActive": 1,
            "AlarmCommunication": [],
            "AlarmWorkingTime": []
        });
   }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Operation/Add',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "SensorID": 0,
            "RoadId": 5
            "GivenSensorID": 3,
            "LocationX": location_x,
            "LocationY": location_y,
            "SegmentId": SegmentID,
            "isActive": 1,
            "Alarm": []
        })
    });
```

Comment: The alarm key is empty in ajax call. you are just sending an empty array. Declare an alarm array, populate it and then send it like "Alarm":alarmArr

Comment: The input doesn't look valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a coma on line 29.

Also, if it doesn't help please provide console output from browser.